# In R, how can I change many select (binary) columns in a dataframe into factors?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset with many columns and I'd like to locate the columns that have fewer than `n` unique responses and change just those columns into factors.

Here is one way I was able to do that:

```
#create sample dataframe
df <- data.frame("number" = c(1,2.7,8,5), "binary1" = c(1,0,1,1), 
"answer" = c("Yes","No", "Yes", "No"), "binary2" = c(0,0,1,0))
n <- 3

#for each column
for (col in colnames(df)){
#check if the first entry is numeric
  if (is.numeric(df[col][1,1])){
# check that there are fewer than 3 unique values
    if ( length(unique(df[col])[,1]) < n ) {
    df[[col]] <- factor(df[[col]])
                                           }
                               }
                         }
```

What is another, hopefully more succinct, way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way using [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/).

We can make use of `where` within `across` to select the columns with logical short-circuit expression where we check

1. the columns are `numeric` - (`is.numeric`)
2. if the 1 is TRUE, check whether number of distinct elements less than the user defined n
3. if 2 is TRUE, then check `all` the `unique` elements in the column are 0 and 1
4. loop over those selected column and convert to `factor` class

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
     mutate(across(where(~is.numeric(.) && 
                           n_distinct(.) < n && 
                           all(unique(.) %in% c(0, 1))),  factor))
```

-checking

```
str(df1)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ number : num  1 2.7 8 5
 $ binary1: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2
 $ answer : chr  "Yes" "No" "Yes" "No"
 $ binary2: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 1
```

Comment: I don't think the `all(unique(.) %in% c(0, 1))` is needed here - kind of makes the `n_distinct(.) < n` useless.

Comment: @GregorThomas Suppose the column have only 0 or 1 alone, I am not sure if the OP wanted to convert those to factor.  Also, unique values can be 2, 3 or 4 or 5.  I guess the OP is specifically looking for those binary

Comment: @GregorThomas I understand your comment, but I think the `n_distinct(.) < n` is including the OP's user defined condition

Comment: Despite their use of "binary" a couple times, the only check OP is attempting in the question is the `n_distinct`. The "binary" columns may just be an example.

Comment: Though you've explained your steps well enough that they should be able to adapt as needed.

Comment: Thanks! This is great. What does the "~" before "is.numeric" do? And what does the "." inside each of your function calls do?

Comment: @Mark The `~` is a compact lambda function in tidyverse which is similar to `function(x)`.  The default value here is `.` or `.x` i.e. the column value.  In `base R`, with new release you can use `\(x) x` as a compact form

Comment: @akrun That may be a great answer, but my only familiarity with any of the things you just said is that  I've used `~` when making formulas like in creating a linear model `lm( outcome~pred1+pred2,df)`. What do you mean by "the column value"? Is `is.numeric(.)` checking whether the entire column is numeric or just a particular value? Do you use the `.` because you're using `across()`?

Comment: @Mark you may have noticed that `where(is.numeric)` in `select`.  Here, I use lambda expression because there are multiple conditions joined by `&&`.  So, either use `~ is.numeric(.) &&` or `function(x) is.numeric(x) &&`.  The lambda expressions are commonly used in `lapply/sapply/apply` based functions in base R as well where the `x` is the column value for that particular column looped

Comment: so it returns false if any part is false for any entry in the column?

Comment: @Mark What it is doing is similar to `lapply(df, function(x) x)` you can print the output and see that it is a vector of column values, Within the `where`, it selects only those columns based on the condition i.e. `lapply(df, function(x) if(is.numeric(x) && othercondition) do this)

Comment: @Mark  All the logical expressions returns a single TRUE/FALSE per column (and that is the reason we wrap with `all` in one of those cases that returns more than one logical value ie. `is.numeric` or `n_distinct(.) < n` or `all(unique(.) %in% c(0, 1))`

Comment: @AnoushiravanR `ifelse` requires all arguments to be same length.  `df[[.y]]` is length  more than the conditioin length which is 1.  You may need `if/else`

Comment: Oh thank you very much. I thought the problem was with the factor function. I will try if else this time. Thanks indeed.

Comment: Dear Arun may I ask you opinion on this very particular quesiton:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68047246/how-to-set-if-condition-for-a-row-of-matrix-inside-for-lapply-function-in-r/68048607#68048607
thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR that post was deleted by you

Comment: @akrun No it was deleted by the author. I just deleted my own answer. I'm sorry anyway to bother you and thank you for taking your time to check that.

Comment: it is ok.  I just clicked on that link and it seems to be deleted. thanks for the reply

Comment: My pleasure, thank you maybe it will come back on.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `imap` function to great advantage in this case. A thousand thanks to my dear friend @akrun who never ceases to inspire us:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

n <- 3

df %>% 
  imap_dfc(~ if(is.numeric(.x) & length(unique((.x)) < n) 
                & all(unique(.x) %in% c(0, 1))) {
    factor(df[[.y]])
    }  else {
      df[[.y]]
  }
)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  number binary1 answer binary2
   <dbl> <fct>   <chr>  <fct>  
1    1   1       Yes    0      
2    2.7 0       No     0      
3    8   1       Yes    1      
4    5   1       No     0
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
out <- list2DF(
    lapply(
        df,
        function(x) {
            if (length(unique(x)) < n & all(x %in% c(0, 1))) as.factor(x) else x
        }
    )
)
```

gives

```
> str(out)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ number : num  1 2.7 8 5
 $ binary1: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2
 $ answer : chr  "Yes" "No" "Yes" "No"
 $ binary2: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 1
```