# How to set if condition for a row of matrix inside for lapply function in R

Tags: r

I have a data set where I need to calculate Kendall's tau pair-wisely (between each pair of variables). I want to store the result in a matrix. However, I would like to find the result and if each value at a current row is less than a specific value, then I would like the loop to stop and do not calculate the next correlation (next row), and return `0` values for all entries for all the next rows. I want to do that with `lapply` function (if possible). In other words, I would like to set a function that works for each row. Then, apply my condition. That is, I can build a function that works for each row separately, then, if the previous row met the condition, all the values in the next rows set to zero.

For example,

Suppose I have the following matrix:

```
structure(c(5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))

Matrix1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5    0    0    0    0
[2,]    4    4    0    0    0
[3,]    3    3    3    0    0
[4,]    1    2    2    2    0
[5,]    2    1    1    1    1
```

Suppose I would like to find the square root of each entry of the matrix row by row. Then, if all entries of each row are `>= 1.6` then, the entries of this row and all comping rows are set to zero, and the `for` loop stop, return me the matrix as follows:

```
Matrix1
         [,1] [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   [,5]
    [1,]    0    0       0      0      0
    [2,]    0    0       0      0      0
    [3,]    0    0       0      0      0
    [4,]    1    1.4     1.4    1.4    0
    [5,]    1.4  1       1      1      1


Any help, please?
```

Comment: I have a suggestion for this case. You might as well go on with your `cor` calculations for the entire data set and after that we could use `lapply` for example to transform values in every row that are below a desired threshold to `0`. Would it work for you? I have just figured out a simple way that may be of interest to you.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I appreciate it. I need to not find the correlation to the entire data as my original function is complicated and this is just an example of what I want. However, I think I can build a function that works for each row separately, and then, if the previous row met the condition, the function stop.

Comment: What is `r.tau`?  Is it created. earlier

Comment: I think in `base R`, the pairwise can be done with `combn` or `outer` or a nested lapply/sapply i.e. `outer(seq_len(ncol(data)), seq_len(ncol(data)), FUN = Vectorize(function(i, j) cor(data[, i], data[, j])))`

Comment: Do you need the condition as `for(i in i1) {
   if(any(r.tau[i, ] <= 0.02 & r.tau[i, ] != 0))
     break 
    for(j in i1) {`

Comment: One thing i am not sure is suppose you have a value 0.94 and 0.01 in a row, do you change the whole row to 0.  With your dput data, I get ` -0.06822729` in the first row itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one with nested `for` loop.

1. Initialize the object to be stored ('r.tau') as a `matrix` with `dim` attributes from the number of cols (`ncol`) of the dataset
2. Do a nested loop on the sequence of columns
3. If the indexes are not equal, calculate the `cor` of the columns subset inside the inner loop
4. Outside the inner loop, add a condition to check whether `all` the values in that particular row (excluding the 0) are less than or equal to 0.2
5. If condition from 4 is TRUE, set the row to 0 and `break` out of the loop

```
r.tau <- matrix(0, ncol(data), ncol(data))
i1 <- seq_len(ncol(data))
for(i in i1) {    
    for(j in i1) {
        if(i != j) {
          r.tau[i, j] <- cor(data[, i], data[, j])
          }
       
       }
       # // just adding print statements for debugging
       print(r.tau[i, ])
       print(all(setdiff(r.tau[i, ], 0) <= 0.2, na.rm = TRUE))
       
      if(all(setdiff(r.tau[i, ], 0) <= 0.2, na.rm = TRUE)) {
        r.tau[i, ] <- 0
        break
        }
    }
```

#### Updated

For the updated condition, we need only a single loop and it can be done from `rev`erse sequence

```
i1 <- rev(seq_len(ncol(Matrix1)))
for(i in i1) {       
        
          Matrix1[i, ] <- sqrt(Matrix1[i, ])
          if(all(setdiff(Matrix1[i, ], 0) >= 1.6)) {
           Matrix1[i:1, ] <- 0
           break
           
          }
           
          
       
       }
```

-output

```
Matrix1
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000    0
[2,] 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000    0
[3,] 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000    0
[4,] 1.000000 1.414214 1.414214 1.414214    0
[5,] 1.414214 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    1
```

---

Or if we need a double loop (for other purpose)

```
i1 <- rev(seq_len(ncol(Matrix1)))
for(i in i1) { 
   for(j in i1) {            
        
       Matrix1[i, j] <- sqrt(Matrix1[i, j])
          }
          if(all(setdiff(Matrix1[i, j], 0) >= 1.6)) {
           Matrix1[i:1, ] <- 0
           break
          }
          
       
       }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it. I need the for loop to test results row by row. If all the entries at a specific row are `<=0.2` then, the loop must stop and set all the coming values for each row to zero.

Comment: I have edited my excepted result (small changes). The idea is that, if for example, all the entries at the current row are 0, then, the loop stops automatically and sets all the entries of upcoming rows to zero.

Comment: We can change `cor` to any other function with a demo example.  My function is so complicated and cannot post it here as it is so long.

Comment: In other words, I would like the code to fit `cor` to each row. Then, if the entires of this row are all zero. Then, the for loop stop and return me a matrix where all the entries are zero. If not, then the `cor` function applied on the second row, if the condition is met, then this row and all next rows are set to zero.

Comment: So, the `cor` function should be applied on each row sequentially one by one starting from the bottom (last row).

Comment: @Maryam If you check the code, I have the `all` check for each row `all(setdiff(r.tau[i, ], 0) <= 0.2, na.rm = TRUE)` excluding the already created 0 s

Comment: @Maryam the issue in testing your data is that I get a different cor values compared to your expected

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your interest in helping me.  The problem is that I cannot share my true data (confidential). Can we try finding the square root function of data stored in a lower rectangular matrix? If so, I will edit my data.

Comment: @Maryam please do edit so that I can reproduce the same results. thanks

Comment: Thanks, I really do not know how to thank you. I have edit the question.

Comment: @Maryam your description `Then, if all entries of each row are >= 1.6 then, the entries of this row and all comping rows are set to zero, and the for loop stop,` and expected is kind of confusing.  In the last row, one value is 1.4.  Does it mean that this is a TRUE negative condition.  also, why are the first couple of rows, values all 0

Comment: the square root function needs to apply on the matrix starting from the last rows to the top.

Comment: @Maryam In your original condition, if a condition is met, then it should break.  But, in this example, it is the reverse going on

Comment: The idea of my original function is to start from bottom to top.

Comment: What I try to do is to make my loop start from bottom to top and make the condition, but I do not know how to do so.

Comment: @Maryam ok, so that means instead of 1:nrow it would be nrow:1

Comment: Yes. That what I need.

Comment: @Maryam Does it also means that there is only a single loop instead of nested because I don't find any condition with using `sqrt` on two rows

Comment: It is only one condition.  I think `sqrt` goes for each entry of each row one by one.

Comment: @Maryam `sqrt` is vectorized,  you don't need to do this one by one.  It can take a single row or the whole matrix as well.  But just for the `for` loop, I am using it on a row

Comment: Excellent. It is what I want. Could you please let me know what is `setdiff` mean?

Comment: @Maryam I added a double loop as well in case you are using non vectorized functions.  `setdiff` will return the values on the first object excluding the one in second one

Comment: It is really great help. I do not know how to thank you. I hope all the best for you.