# how to set a value at a current level to zero based on the previous values

Tags: r

I have data, I would like to run a complex function to this data. The idea of the function is that, if the value of current element is `>` specific value, then the value of all coming element need to set to `0`. For example,

suppose my data is `x <- 1:16` Then, I want to find the square root of each value from `1` to `16`, if we get a square root larger than `3`, then the loop must stop and set all the coming values to `0`.

For example, the square root of `9` is `3`. Hence, the function must stop here and set all the values of the element from `9` to `16` to `0`.

Here is my try:

```
xy <- list()
for (i in seq_along(x)){
  xy[[i]] <- myfunc(x[i])
  if (xy[[i]] > 3 ) 
    break
  xy[[i]] <- 0
}
```

So I expect the values to be like this:

```
     > xy
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1.4

[[3]]
[1] 1.7

[[4]]
[1] 2

[[5]]
[1] 2.2

[[6]]
[1] 2.4

[[7]]
[1] 2.6

[[8]]
[1] 2.8

[[9]]
[1] 0

[[10]]
[1] 0
 
[[11]]
[1] 0

[[10]]
[1] 0

[[12]]
[1] 0

[[13]]
[1] 0

 [[14]]
[1] 0

[[15]]
[1] 0

[[16]]
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you can use this:

```
x <- 1:16
out <- vector("list", length = length(x))
for(i in seq_along(x)) {
   if(sqrt(x[i]) < 3) {
     out[[i]] <- sqrt(x[i])
   } else {
     out[i:length(x)] <- 0
   }
}
out
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1.414214

[[3]]
[1] 1.732051

[[4]]
[1] 2

[[5]]
[1] 2.236068

[[6]]
[1] 2.44949

[[7]]
[1] 2.645751

[[8]]
[1] 2.828427

[[9]]
[1] 0

[[10]]
[1] 0

[[11]]
[1] 0

[[12]]
[1] 0

[[13]]
[1] 0

[[14]]
[1] 0

[[15]]
[1] 0

[[16]]
[1] 0
```

Comment: My pleasure and I'm sorry I couldn't offer much help in the other one. Actually I asked a friend of mine to take a look at your previous question if you decided to post it again in the coming hours he can definitely help you.

Comment: Thanks. I really do not know how to thank you for your help. I will reposted it again.

Comment: Anything & anytime for my compatriots. Post it I will ask him again.

Comment: I was thinking that it is a dupe.  There is much more into it.  I reopened.

Comment: @akrun no no it's ok, I asked her to repost the main question. Then I will be grateful if you could take a look at that.

Comment: Dear @akrun I think the question I was referring to has been reopened. I would be grateful if you could just take a look at it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68047246/how-to-set-if-condition-for-a-row-of-matrix-inside-for-lapply-function-in-r?noredirect=1#comment120272811_68047246
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR thanks will look into it.  I couldn't understand some objects `r.tau`

Comment: No, nothing in particular. Just we start by measuring `cor` for every combination of columns of the data set. Then we store the result in a correlation matrix which is called `r.tau`. For example when we measure `cor` for column `1` and every other columns `1:4` the result will be store in row 1 and column `1:4` of the `r.tau` matrix. So obvisouly `r.tau[i,i]` are all equal to `1` and for example `r.tau[i, j]` is equal to `r.tau[j, i]`.

Comment: But the point is the OP wants to keep calculating the correlation until she reaches a row in `r.tau` when all values are less than a certain threshold at stops it.

Comment: Yes that was the case I was struggling with, I decided to set another threshold but it appeared all of them were in a certain range. Maybe she could explain more about the conditions. Thank you very much for your help and support, much appreciated.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I added a modified solution.  Probably, that works for the OP

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much indeed. It was quite a question.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR thanks, I added a assignment as well before the break to change that row to 0

Comment: So one single `0` is enough, I thought I have to create a vector that multiplies the col number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vectorized operations

```
x <- 1:16

val <- sqrt(x)
ifelse(cumsum(val >3), 0, val)
# [1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000 2.236068
# [6] 2.449490 2.645751 2.828427 3.000000 0.000000
# [11] 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
# [16] 0.000000
```

Here we talk your `x` values and find the square root and then use the `cumsum()` (cumulative sum) function along with your boolean check to see if any values pass the check. Basically FALSE values are 0 so when you take the cumulative sum it stays zero, but when you get the first TRUE value the cumulative sum will stay larger than 1 which will just be TRUE. Here all values after the first will be set to 0 by `ifelse`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help. Is there any way to keep it as a list. As my function require a loop or `lapply` function

Answer (score 0):

A few more ways

```r
#one way
purrr::map(1:16, ~ ifelse(sqrt(.x) > 3, 0, sqrt(.x)))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1.414214
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1.732051
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 2.236068
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 2.44949
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 2.645751
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 2.828427
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[11]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[12]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[13]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[14]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[15]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[16]]
#> [1] 0

#2nd way
Map(\(.x) ifelse(sqrt(.x) > 3, 0, sqrt(.x)), 1:16)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1.414214
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1.732051
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 2.236068
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 2.44949
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 2.645751
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 2.828427
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[11]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[12]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[13]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[14]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[15]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[16]]
#> [1] 0

#3rd way
lapply(1:16, \(.x) ifelse(sqrt(.x) > 3, 0, sqrt(.x)))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1.414214
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1.732051
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 2.236068
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 2.44949
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 2.645751
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 2.828427
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[11]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[12]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[13]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[14]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[15]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[16]]
#> [1] 0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>